# why isn't my proof valid? system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

The problem was: given the matrix $A \in M_{m\times n}$ and let $b \in F^{m}_{col}$.
$y \in F^{m}_{col}$ is a solution of the system of equations $AX=b$.
prove: every solution of the system of equations $AX=b$ can be represented as $y+x$, where $x \in F^{m}_{col}$ is the solution of the homogeneous system $AX=0$.

so my proof was like that:
because $y \in F^{m}_{col}$ is a solution of the system of equations $AX=b$ we can conclude:
$$(1) A \cdot y=b$$
and because $x \in F^{m}_{col}$ is a solution of the system of equations $AX=0$ we can conclude:
$$(2) A \cdot x=0$$
from (1) and (2) we get:
$$ A \cdot y+A \cdot x=0+b$$
according to the rules of matrix multiplication we get:
$$(3) A \cdot ( y+ x)=0+b=b$$
and therefore according to (3) the solution which is represented by $z=x+y$ is also a solution of the system of equations $AX=b$

my instructor gave me only 3 points for that telling that "it isn't a valid proof". Why is that? what's the problem with it? and what should I say in order to appeal his decision.
thank in advance.

Comment: You are only verifying that $y+x$ is a solution, not every solution is of the form $y+x$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part that you missed: let $\;z\;$ be a solution, *any* solution, to $\;Ax=b\;$ , then

$$A(z-y)=Az-Ay=b-b=0\implies \;z-y\;\text{is a solution to the hom. system}\;\;Ax=0$$

and thus there exists $\;t\in\;$ space of all solutions to the hom. sytem, such that

$$z-y=t\implies z=t+y$$

with $\;t\;$ a solution to the hom. system, and $\;y\;$ a particular solution to the non-hom. system